# Convert an array of timestamps to seconds in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, timestamp

I'm new to SO and Matlab so please excuse any transgressions. 
I'm trying to convert a seemingly simple array of timestamp strings to an equivalent array of seconds.

I wrote a this function:

```
% Function to calculate seconds from a timestamp in the following format:
% ddd hh:mm:ss.SSSS (example: 123 12:59:00.9999)
function a = TimestampToS(stamp)

% Uses the "named tokens" facility of MATLAB's "regexp" function.
expr = ['(?<ddd>\d+)' ...                % ddd
        ' ' ...                          % Space " " separator
        '(?<hh>\d+)' ...                 % hh
        ':' ...                          % Colon ":" separator
        '(?<mm>\d+)' ...                 % mm
        ':' ...                          % Colon ":" separator
        '(?<ss>\d+)' ...                 % ss
        '.' ...                          % Dot "." separator
        '(?<SSSS>\d+)'];                 % SSSS

    parsedStamp = regexp(stamp, expr, 'names');

a = (str2double(parsedStamp.ddd) * 86400) + ...
    (str2double(parsedStamp.hh) * 3600) + ...
    (str2double(parsedStamp.mm) * 60) + ...
    (str2double(parsedStamp.ss)) + ...
    (str2double(parsedStamp.SSSS) * 0.0001);
```

It works great for an individual string:

```
>> TimestamptoS('123 12:59:00.9999')

ans =

    1.067394099990000e+007
```

But if I try to use a cell array I get:

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

How can I get an array of seconds?  I have tried all kinds of conversions of the input data and "parsedStamp" but nothing works.  I don't understand Matlab or its matrix notation well enough.  Any help gratefully received!
PS This is not a regexp question, no replies about regexp please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it very easily without modifying your function, by using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). This essentially extracts each cell of the cell array and passes it to your function.

```
>> cellArray = {'123 12:59:00.9999','130 12:59:00.9999'}; % for example

>> cellfun(@TimestampToS,cellArray)

ans =
  1.0e+007 *
   1.067394099990000   1.127874099990000
```

Comment: Perfect answer Luis, thank you for your time. I hope this serves as a reference for others in future! PS Sorry I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote.